# jQuery change blur event only working for first element in list

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having a problem - my jQuery change blur event is only working for the first element in a dynamically created list. How can I resolve this?

The element I've created (well a watered down version) can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/kfm5b/2/

jQuery

```
$('.roomFac').on("change blur", function () {
    var park = $("#park2").val();
    var lecturestyle = $("#lecture_style2").val();
    var roomstructure = $("#room_structure2").val();
    var groupsize = $("#groupSize2").val();
    var facilities = "";
    $('select[name*=roomFac]').each(function () {
        facilities += $(this).val();
        facilities += ",";
    });
    var dataString = 'park=' + park + '&' + 'lecturestyle=' + lecturestyle + '&' +
        'roomstructure=' + roomstructure + '&' + 'groupsize=' + groupsize + '&' +
        'facilities=' + facilities;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableMon2.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#mon').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

**process_timetableMon2.php**

```
$array = explode(",", $_POST["facilities"]);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    echo $array[$i].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: If you've already set up a jsFiddle go ahead and add the fucntion you're trying to fix, to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since the select dropdowns are added dynamically, you need a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('change blur', '.roomFac', function () {
    //Your function here
});
```